# How to use GeoDjango PostGIS ForceRHR/ForcePolygonCW

Tags: postgis, geodjango

I have a model with a field called 'geom' that is a MultiPolygonField. When I query for instances of the model, I'd like the data in this field to follow the right hand rule. Because I am using PostGIS on the back end, I have support for ForceRHR (I am using Django 2.06), but I can't figure out how to use it.

In views.py, I get a URL request with name value pairs, and I convert that dictionary into a dictionary suitable for use in a filter:

```
def field_datasets(request):
    client_name = 'MSFF'
    grower = Growers.objects.filter(name__exact=client_name).get()

    fields = serialize('geojson', Fields.objects.filter(grower__exact=grower.id).filter(
    Q(*[(k,v)for k,vs in request.GET.lists() for v in vs], _connector=Q.OR)
    ))

    return HttpResponse(fields, content_type='json'
```

I've tried this:

```
...
    test = Fields.objects.filter(grower__exact=grower.id).filter(
        Q(*[(k,v)for k,vs in request.GET.lists() for v in vs], _connector=Q.OR)
    )

    test.update(geom = ForceRHR('geom'))
    fields = serialize('geojson', test)
...
```

and I've tried this:

```
...
    test = Fields.objects.filter(grower__exact=grower.id).filter(
        Q(*[(k,v)for k,vs in request.GET.lists() for v in vs], _connector=Q.OR)
    )

    for item in test:
        rhr_geom = ForceRHR(item.geom)
        test[item].geom = rhr_geom

    fields = serialize('geojson', test)
...
```

The documentation says: 
Accepts a single geographic field or expression and returns a modified version of the polygon/multipolygon in which all exterior rings are oriented clockwise and all interior rings are oriented counterclockwise. Non-polygonal geometries are returned unchanged.

So how else do you pass a geographic field?